# How to get cron to pkill my java process?

Tags: cron, kill, pkill

I have a cron job that runs to detect if a certain application has frozen. If so it should kill the frozen application and restart it. The application is a Java program. When the application is frozen, my cron job tries to kill it using `pkill -9 java`, but it says permission not given due to cron not being able to kill `java`. But I can run this command fine as the user. What am I doing wrong?

*update below is the cron line i use:

```
*/20 * * * * /bin/bash /home/userabc/node_checker.sh >> /home/userabc/node_checker.log
```

That runs this file:

[image]

The cron runs that .sh file but in my logs I'm getting permission denied. I'm assuming its because of the user cron?

Comment: `cron not being able to kill java` is not true - it just depends on which user is running the `crontab`. Also, your problem sounds like it would be easier to handle if you ran the java application as a service.

Comment: It may help if you edited your question and added the exact crontab entry you're using, the owner of that crontab, the exact command that executes Java (and the user that runs it), and the exact error message you get (is it a log entry?). Of course, after removing anything that you prefer not to disclose. It is otherwise hard to guess what could be going wrong. Thank you. Also, please check if the error you are getting isn't due to your cron job not being able to kill some _unintended_ Java process owned by a different user.

Comment: You seem to paraphrase the error message.  Please edit your question and include the exact error message.

Comment: thanks. I forgot the exact error as I deleted the cron mail that gets sent out if there are errors. It had something to do with permission issue as it couldnt pkill the java process. I've also updated the question to include more details. @fra-san

Comment: Thank you for your edit. You can likely retrieve cron's error messages from your logs (the exact command/file varies, depending on your OS). // Please, whenever possible copy/paste text into your question instead of posting images of text. // The user that cron runs jobs as is the crontab owner, and this relevant detail (which user runs the java process? And which user is the owner of that cron job?) is still missing in your question.